# Set character length of a field in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I set a character length for a number field? Additionally how can I set the character length of a text-box (Alpha/Numeric) field?

I have looked through documentation and attempted using a calculation to set this, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. This is a feature that we are looking to add in a later release. Until that release we do not have a way to limit the length of a number field or a text field. You can follow the progress of this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/Rtq9Rl0I).